# Recursion in Pyparsing

Tags: python, recursion, pyparsing, ebnf

Im unable to translate this EBNF expression into Pyparsing, any idea?

```
token:: [A-Z]
P:: !|token;P|(P^P)|(P*P)
```

The problem is when using recursion, the interpreter fails.
Expression like this should be valid:

```
(ASD;!^FFF;!)
A;B;C;!
(((A;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build a recursive grammar with Pyparsing, you have to think a little inside-out, using pyparsing's Forward class. With Forward, you define an empty placeholder for an expression to be defined later.  Here is a start at pyparsing for this BNF:

```
EXCLAM,SEMI,HAT,STAR = map(Literal,"!;^*")
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress,"()")
token = oneOf(list(alphas.upper()))
```

I'm using Literal for defining your operators, but suppressing the grouping ()'s, we'll use pyparsing Group to physically group the results into sublists.

Now we define the placeholder expression with Forward:

```
expr = Forward()
```

And now we can build the expression using this placeholder (we have to use '<<=' as the assignment operator so that expr is maintained as a Forward, and not rebound to the expression itself). Here is my first pass, using your BNF as-is:

```
expr <<= (EXCLAM | 
          token + SEMI + expr | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + STAR + expr + RPAR))
```

This gives these results:

```
(ASD;!^FFF;!)
  ^
Expected ";" (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)

A;B;C;!
['A', ';', 'B', ';', 'C', ';', '!']

(((A;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)
[[[['A', ';', '!', '^', 'B', ';', '!'], '^', 'C', ';', 'D', ';', '!'], '*', 'E', ';', '!']]
```

It seems there is an unwritten rule in your BNF, that one or more tokens together can be present also, easily fixed as:

```
expr <<= (EXCLAM | 
          OneOrMore(token) + SEMI + expr | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + STAR + expr + RPAR))
```

Now giving:

```
(ASD;!^FFF;!)
[['A', 'S', 'D', ';', '!', '^', 'F', 'F', 'F', ';', '!']]

A;B;C;!
['A', ';', 'B', ';', 'C', ';', '!']

(((A;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)
[[[['A', ';', '!', '^', 'B', ';', '!'], '^', 'C', ';', 'D', ';', '!'], '*', 'E', ';', '!']]
```

But it looks like we could benefit from additional grouping, so that the operands for the binary '^' and '*' operators are more clearly grouped.  So I settled on:

```
expr <<= (EXCLAM | 
          Group(OneOrMore(token) + SEMI + ungroup(expr)) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + STAR + expr + RPAR) )
```

And I think this version of the output will be more easily processed now:

```
(ASD;!^FFF;!)
[[['A', 'S', 'D', ';', '!'], '^', ['F', 'F', 'F', ';', '!']]]

A;B;C;!
[['A', ';', 'B', ';', 'C', ';', '!']]

(((A;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)
[[[[['A', ';', '!'], '^', ['B', ';', '!']], '^', ['C', ';', 'D', ';', '!']], '*', ['E', ';', '!']]]
```

Here is the complete script:

```
from pyparsing import *

EXCLAM,SEMI,HAT,STAR = map(Literal,"!;^*")
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress,"()")
token = oneOf(list(alphas.upper()))
expr = Forward()
expr <<= (EXCLAM | 
          Group(OneOrMore(token) + SEMI + ungroup(expr)) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR) | 
          Group(LPAR + expr + STAR + expr + RPAR) )

tests = """\
(ASD;!^FFF;!)
A;B;C;!
(((A;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)""".splitlines()

for t in tests:
    print t
    try:
        print expr.parseString(t).dump()
    except ParseException as pe:
        print ' '*pe.loc + '^'
        print pe
    print
```

Last note: I assumed that "AAA" was 3 successive 'A' tokens.  If you meant for tokens to be word groupings of 1 or more alphas, then change 'OneOrMore(token)' in the expression to 'Word(alphas.upper())' - then you'll get this result for your first test case:

```
[[['ASD', ';', '!'], '^', ['FFF', ';', '!']]]
```

Comment: Woow you did the trick!

Just, one more question...

I will like to update the binary operators like * and ^ to prefix notation, like Lisp. In the documentation there is an example using strings, but not sure how to translate it to arrays.

Something like:
`
Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR) to
Group(LPAR + expr + expr + HAT+ RPAR)
`

Comment: `expr expr HAT` sounds like *postfix* notation to me.  Won't that work the way you have it?  If you want equal precedence for STAR and HAT, try `Group(LPAR + expr + expr + (STAR | HAT) + RPAR)`.

Answer (score 1):

This make the Lisp notation work xD !!

```
from pyparsing import *

def pushFirst( strg, loc, toks ):
    toks[0][2], toks[0][1] = toks[0][1], toks[0][2]

def parseTerm(term):
    """
    EBNF syntax elements
    EXCLAM =  !
    HAT =  ^ 
    STAR =  *
    SEMI =  ; 
    LPAR =  (
    RPAR =  )
    """

    EXCLAM,HAT,STAR = map(Literal,"!^*")
    LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress,"()")
    SEMI = Suppress(";")

    token = oneOf(list(alphas.upper()))
    expr = Forward()
    expr <<=    (
                    EXCLAM | 
                    Group(Word(alphas.upper()) + SEMI + ungroup(expr)) | 
                    Group(LPAR + expr + HAT + expr + RPAR).setParseAction( pushFirst ) | 
                    Group(LPAR + expr + STAR + expr + RPAR).setParseAction( pushFirst )
                )
    try:
        result = expr.parseString(term)   
    except ParseException as pe:
        print ' '*pe.loc + '^'
        print pe
    return result[0]



def computeTerm(term):
    print term


term = (parseTerm("(((AXX;!^B;!)^C;D;!)*E;!)"))

computeTerm(term)
```

Comment: Well, that's brute force, but looks like you have transcended to the second level of pyparsingness, using parse actions.  Congrats, and have fun with pyparsing!